# Show that a certain set of $n \times n$ matrices is a subspace of vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

how do I prove (or disprove) that the set

$$\left\{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \mid A X+X B+X^{T} C+D X^{T}=0\right\}$$

is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}\,$?

I only know that the zero vector exists, but I don't know how to proceed further.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let the set you defined be $S$. All you need to do is show that
$$X,Y\in S\implies X+Y\in S$$
and
$$X\in S\implies cX\in S$$
for any $c\in\mathbb R$. Can you see how to do this?

Comment: I know that to prove that the set is part of the subspace I also need to prove that the sum of the two vectors from the same set are still part of the same set but I am just wondering where do I get the "Y" mentioned in your example.

Comment: @tristan321 the $Y$ is just another element of the set. Put another way, if
$$AX+XB+X^TC+DX^T=0$$
and
$$AY+YB+Y^TC+DY^T=0,$$
then is
$$A(X+Y)+(X+Y)B+(X+Y)^TC+D(X+Y)^T$$
zero?

Comment: Well it should be since if we say that A,B,C,D are zero then the values of X and Y don't matter.

Comment: Or rather if X,Y are equal to zero since A,B,C,D are considered constants. But either way it should be zero, right?

Comment: @tristan321 None of the matrices $A,B,C,D,X,Y$ needs to be zero. You only have to answer this: if the equation holds for both $X$ and $Y$, does it still hold for $X+Y$ and $cX$?

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea how I would prove that.